# Fully Control The Location of an Image with CSS for Squarespace site

Tags: css, image, squarespace

I am trying to move 3 images so that they line up and are the same distance from each other.
Here is the site.

https://www.leonardwarren.net/personal-training

I need the bottom 3 images to have about the same sized white gap in between each other.

To create these images I used Custom CSS to make a mouse hover effect.

I used this code in the code block for each image:

```
<div class="image-swap">
  <img src="image">
  <img src="imageonhover">
</div>
```

That code stacks the images on top of each other.

I then made this code for the hover effect

If you go to the website, You will see the spacing is off.

Comment: .image-swap img:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .6s;
}

.image-swap img:nth-child(1):hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-swap2 img:nth-child(1) {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .6s;
}

.image-swap2 img:nth-child(1):hover {
  opacity: 0;
}                                                                                                                                                              This code here is under the custom CSS portion of my site.

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is off because your images have different widths. Try to set the thesame widths for all of them, it should solve the problem.

I would use something like this:

```
.content-wrapper img {
width: 100em;
height: 20em;
```

}